# access to many fb marketing accounts through one fb app

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Currently my fb app has only developer level access.
Is it possible to get data from a marketing account which is connected with nameX fb account from my fb app which is connected with nameY fb account?
I've tried to do an API call 'act_' about such marketing account, but all I've got is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10
  }
}
```

I know obviously about a business marketing platform where you can create a few marketing accounts, but I'm looking for smth more. 
Currently 2 marketing accounts are connected to my fb app. The calls to the one which is on the same fb account as the app work.
BTW, My  is on the fb business marketing platform.

Answer (score 2):

I think your app is on development-tier of marketing api app - that's why it has limited number of accessible adaccounts. You could go to developer dashboard (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/review-status/) to apply for business management permission, and then you're good to go.